# Can two contradicting ideas be put together in the same sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence, antonyms

I have written a paragraph in which I have described that a person's fingers are both smooth as glass and bumpy as a rocky road at the same time. I was criticised for this statement, but I do not think that such statements are wrong. Please help.

Comment: "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times . . ." (Charles Dickens, start reading [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/98/pg98.txt)).

Comment: *Ours is essentially a tragic age, so we refuse to take it tragically* D.H.Lawrence *Lady Chatterley's Lover*. Not sure if that counts.

Comment: A government report would say:  "It was the best of times, but, on the other hand, it was the worst of times."

Comment: Robusto's Dickens quote is a wonderful oxymoron. Putting together two conflicting statements without a sensible deeper interpretation is a contradiction in terms, and to be avoided unless one wants to sound Pythonesque.

Comment: *And she aches just like a woman, 
But she breaks just like a little girl.* - Mr. Dylan

Comment: Putting together contradicting ideas is not in any way an error in grammar.  Whether it's an error in semantics depends on how effective the writer is and how perceptive the reader is.  If everyone in the world were purely literal-minded, *A Tale of Two Cities* would never even have been published.

Comment: Too much is not enough.  Hurry up and wait.  I found it hard, hard to find.  Well whatever, nevermind

Comment: Rocky and glass, are practically antonyms of one another. I don't think they work very well together. Perhaps *knotted*, *knobbly* and *gnarled* fingers match closer with the cold silkiness of glass

Comment: The bumps are always smoother over the top of the hill.

Comment: I don't think it matters whether they're in the same sentence or not. If they're contradictory, the contradiction exists if they're in separate sentences. If the two descriptions refer to different contexts (like the Dickens quote), and this is explained later, it doesn't matter if you put them in the same or different sentences.

Comment: The examples given in the comments demonstrate how contradictions can serve a literary purpose. They intrigue the reader/listener, spurring him to keep reading to understand the deeper meaning.

Answer (score 1):

> Can two contradicting ideas be put together in the same sentence?

Yes they can, but should they?

> fingers are both smooth as glass and bumpy as a rocky road

This is a powerful writing style.  But it is easy to abuse.  Making it difficult to judge without more context.

If you do this with every little thing you describe it quickly becomes tiresome.

If you are confronting the reader with a contradiction that has a deeper meaning to be appreciated then you should actually take the criticism as a complement.  You want your writing to have impact.  At the least you've provoked a response.  Just be sure it's the response you want.  Don't hang on to this wording simply out of stubbornness.  Just because your statements are not wrong doesn't mean your writing is good.

With that out of the way I'll say that a literal interpretation isn't actually contradictory.  It's just that most of us are familiar with flat glass.  Few with bumpy glass.  Lay on a bed strewn with perfectly smooth glass figurines and I think you'd find it bumpy.  Just lay gently, or you'll also find it jagged.

Like this you can guide your reader through what seems a contradiction.  You've created a dissonance that the reader wants to see resolved.  It's good to confront contradictions.  Just treat them with care or they'll sound as much like music as a drum set falling down a flight of stairs.